# Parallel and Distributing Computing

Tags: image-processing, parallel-processing

You have an image-processing application that needs to process 1,000 images daily, which are 4 mebibytes
(MiB, 220 or 1,048,576 bytes) each in size. It takes 10 min in serial to process each image. Your cluster is
composed of multi-core nodes with 16 cores and a total of 16 gibibytes (GiB, 230 bytes, or 1024 mebibytes)
of main memory storage per node. (Note that we use the proper binary terms, MiB and GiB, rather than MB
and GB, which are the metric terms for 106 and 109 bytes, respectively.)

1. What parallel processing design best handles this workload?
2. Now customer demand increases by 10x. Does your design handle this?
3. What changes would you have to make?

I tried to provide an explanation of the provided problem, expecting to clarify its importance

Comment: Please show your own attempt at a design.